# Java - Obtaining generic object as String Generic type throws exception

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, generic-collections

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T element;

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}

public class Test  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Box> l = new ArrayList<>(); //Just List of Box with no specific type
        Box<String> box1 = new Box<>();
        box1.setElement("aa");
        Box<Integer> box2 = new Box<>();
        box2.setElement(10);

        l.add(box1);
        l.add(box2);

        //Case 1
        Box<Integer> b1 = l.get(0);
        System.out.println(b1.getElement()); //why no error

        //Case 2
        Box<String> b2 = l.get(1);
        System.out.println(b2.getElement()); //throws ClassCastException

    }
}
```

The list `l` holds element of type `Box`. In case 1, I get the first element as `Box<Integer>` and in second case the second element in the list is obtained as `Box<String>`. The ClassCastException is not thrown in the first case.

When I tried to debug, the `element's` type in `b1` and `b2` are `String` and `Integer` respectively.

Is it related to type erasure?

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/IcoVrZ)

Comment: My guess would be that `b1` is considered like `Box<Object>` at runtime but this is indeed a strange behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be precise, the problem is `PrintStream#println`.

Let's check the compiled code using `javap -c Test.class`:

```
72: invokevirtual #12        // Method blub/Box.getElement:()Ljava/lang/Object;
75: invokevirtual #13        // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

As you can see the compiler erased the types and also omitted a cast for `Integer`, because it wasn't necessary here. The compiler already linked the used overloaded methoded to [`PrintStream#(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-).
It does that due to the [JLS rule §5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3):

> *Method invocation conversion* is applied to each argument value in a method or constructor invocation ([§8.8.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1), [§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), [§15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)): the type of the argument expression must be converted to the type of the corresponding parameter.
>
> Method invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion ([§5.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.1))
> - a widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8))
> - a widening reference conversion ([§5.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8))
> - a boxing conversion ([§5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) optionally followed by widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

The third rule is the conversion from a subtype to a supertype:

> A *widening reference* conversion exists from any reference type S to any reference type T, provided S is a subtype ([§4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10)) of T.

And is done before the check if the type can be unboxed (the fifth check: *"an unboxing conversion"*). So the compiler checks that `Integer` is a subtype of `Object` and therefore it has to call `#println(Object)` (your IDE will tell you the same if you check the called overloaded version).

The second version on the other hand:

```
 95: invokevirtual #12        // Method blub/Box.getElement:()Ljava/lang/Object;
 98: checkcast     #14        // class java/lang/String
101: invokevirtual #15        // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

has a `checkcast` to check of the retrieved type of `Box#getElement` really is a `String`. This is necessary, because your told the compiler it will be a `String` (due to the generic type `Box<String> b2 = l.get(1);`) and it linked the method [`PrintStream#(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-). This check fails with the mentioned `ClassCastException`, because an `Integer` cannot be cast to `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the problem here is that b2 is *incorrectly* marked as being `Box<String>` when it's actually `Box<Integer>` (the type of box2) - so `b2.getElement()` is typed as String, even though it actually contains an Integer. The compiler tries to call the overloaded println method which takes a String rather than the method which takes an Object and so you get a ClassCastException. The Object version of println does an explicit conversion of its argument to a String (via a call to toString()) but the String version of the method doesn't do that.

The underlying problem is using raw types rather than fully specifying the type parameter for list `l` - it should have been `List<Box<?>>`. Then you'd have had `b1` and `b2` as Box and the right overload of System.out.println would have been chosen.

Comment: So the reason that this problem doesn't occur when I try to call `b1.getElement()` is that println with Object parameter is called?

Comment: Yes, b1 is also incorrectly typed but at runtime it doesn't matter because it gets cast to Object.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time the compiler knows the type and links the call of `System.out.println(..)` to the method with the correct parameter type. In the first case the compiler resolves the call to `println(Object)`. Because `b1.getElement()` returns an `Object`, `String` is an `Object`, the method call is correct and raises no exception. In the second case the compiler resolves the call to `println(String)`, because of `Box<String>`, but `b2.getElement()` returns an `Integer`. This cannot be cast to String and a `ClassCastException` is raised.

Comment: So system.out.println(10) doesn't work, in your opinion.

Comment: `b.getElement()` returns an `Integer`. I think you meant println version that takes Object as parameter is called.

Answer (score 0):

The method println is not defined for Integer parameter so your code will call println(Object object) which will call object.toString() to get the string it needs to print out. There is no type checking because everything is an Object.

In the second case your code wants to call println(String someString) and because of that it will check if someString is really a String and because it is not it is going to throw an exception.